# Google Script: Copy row to another sheet on edit ALMOST THERE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've spent hours trying to get this to work so any help is much appreciated I've got the code below copying from my main sheet to logs. However the code I'm trying to alter looks to column 10 for the sheet name. I'd like this just to default to the sheet logs any idea what needs changing to make this happen? Thanks in advance

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // see Sheet event objects docs
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  
  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = 9;
  var nameCol = 10;
  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18L5-RGHBx41sMtvC1-7AoVCo6y3imvtELQFjkhPXtoY')
  var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('logs');
  
  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  
  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
  
  // if our action/status col is changed to yes do stuff
  if (e.value == "Yes" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
   var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after
      r.setValue("Logged")
      // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on your sheet/column structure. Maybe link a screenshot.

Comment: @janniks the headers are like this  Whats Due Description       Due For Date Due Status            Provider           Account Number           Price Paid            Notes          Update

Comment: @janniks Here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18L5-RGHBx41sMtvC1-7AoVCo6y3imvtELQFjkhPXtoY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get a `sheet` by it's name.

---

The following code will return the sheet named `Logs`.

```js
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Logs');
```

---

Google Apps Script Documentation: [`getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

Comment: sorry I'm really new to coding where would i place that? Thanks

Comment: @jenniks Ok very odd but once i changed the sheet name from logs to sheet (and renamed the sheet) the code now works!!!! Odd but it now works thank you